# How to run two commands on Github Actions instance one after another?

Tags: django, github-actions, cicd

So question seems easy but let me start with this, "**;**" "**&**" does not work.

The two commands to be ran on Github actions instance in **CI/CD pipeline** :

1. `python3 manage.py runserver`
2. `python3 abc.py`

After putting the command in the yaml file, only the first command runs and then the workflow is stuck there only and does not executes the second command.

I have tried putting in two separate blocks in workflow yaml file but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are two to run commands one after another on Github Actions.

On the same step:

```yaml
   steps:
      - name: Run both python files
        run: |
          python manage.py runserver
          python abc.py
```

On different steps (that will run in sequence):

```yaml
   steps:
      - name: Run first python file
        run: python manage.py runserver

      - name: Run second python file
        run: python abc.py
```

Also, you don't need to inform `python3`, just python is enough, as you will use the `setup/python` action informing the version first.

Therefore, your whole workflow would probably look like this:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository content
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4

      - name: Setup Python Version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8

      - name: Install Python dependencies
        run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip [...] # if necessary

      - name: Execute Python scripts
        run: |
          python manage.py runserver
          python abc.py
```

Comment: Hey GuiFalourd, I have tried exact same thing but the tests get stuck on python manage.py run server.

Comment: Hmm, is that case it's probably because you never stop the server from running.
Therefore the script runs until you get a timeout from the github actions runner.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to stop the server as the file used in second command makes request to the recently deployed server. Also I don't even see my second command getting executed.

Comment: In that case, you would probably have to run both script in separated jobs, or workflows (in parallel). But you would need to know the server address somehow to run the second script.

Comment: I got it working using "nohup" and then using "exit 0" to exit out of the shell. After that running the second command. Since the server is running in the background and we exit the shell with "exit 0"  and run the next command.

Comment: Great! :D Fell free to had the answer or edit mine.